# Laravel : Generate PDF file using Dompdf

Tags: laravel, pdf, laravel-5, dompdf

i am submitting a search form and based on the posted values results are fetched from DB and shown on the result page. I want to download these results in a PDF file. I configured Dompdf and its downloading PDF with some test data as below :

```
public function Genderate_PDF()
    {
        $data = ['title' => 'some title'];
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf', $data);      
        return $pdf->download('mypdf.pdf');
    }
```

but in my scenario instead of loading the pdf view I have to show results in a page and then export that page results to PDF on a button click( Export PDF). Can someone please guide me how can i achieve that

**EDIT::**

Below is the search result posted to view that i need to export as PDF

```
public function search(Request $request){

        $result = \DB::table('matromonial_data');
        if ($request->has('gender')) {
            $result->where('gender', $request->input('gender'));
        }


        if ($request->has('age_from') &&  $request->has('age_to')) {
            $datefrom=$request->input('age_from');
            $dateto=$request->input('age_to');
            $result->where(function($query) use ($datefrom,$dateto){
                $query->whereBetween('age',array($datefrom,$dateto)) ;
            });
        }


        if ($request->has('height_from') &&  $request->has('height_to')) {
            $height_from=$request->input('height_from');
            $height_to=$request->input('height_to');
            $result->where(function($query) use ($height_from,$height_to){
                $query->whereBetween('height',array($height_from,$height_to)) ;
            });
        }


        if ($request->has('religion')) {
            $result->whereIn('religion', $request->input('religion'));
        }

        if ($request->has('cast')) {
            $result->whereIn('cast', $request->input('cast'));
        }

        if ($request->has('mother_tongue')) {
            $result->whereIn('mother_tongue', $request->input('mother_tongue'));
        }

        if ($request->has('maritial_status')) {
            $result->whereIn('maritial_status', $request->input('maritial_status'));
        }

        if ($request->has('country')) {
            $result->whereIn('country', $request->input('country'));
        }
        if ($request->has('city')) {
            $result->whereIn('city', $request->input('city'));
        }

        if ($request->has('profession')) {
            $result->whereIn('profession', $request->input('profession'));
        }
        if ($request->has('education')) {
            $result->whereIn('education', $request->input('education'));
        }


        if ($request->has('income')) {
            $result->whereIn('income', $request->input('income'));
        }
        if ($request->has('keywords')) {
            $result->where('keywords',  'like','%' . $request->input('keywords') .'%');
        }
        if ($request->has('smoking_status')) {
            $result->where('smoking_status', $request->input('smoking_status'));
        }

        if ($request->has('drinking_status')) {
            $result->where('drinking_status', $request->input('drinking_status'));
        }
        $data['result_set']=$result->get();

        return view('admin/search_result', $data);
    }
```

Comment: update your question with the search functionality..

Comment: updated the code pls check

Comment: you can send these search data to export pdf function like with hidden fields in a form and render the view to export to pdf.

Comment: okay so once the form is posted data is rendered in search results , how do i get these values again should i save them in session to repost from the view ?

Comment: just resend them to the view.

Comment: return view('admin/search_result', $data); here data is alrady sent to the view and view is loaded how do i resend it please guide

Comment: send request variable as well to this view.

Comment: that's what i am not sure about how do i do that